# SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg in arguments function

Tags: python, function, arguments, args

I have this functions:

```
def crypting(self, client, access_token, client_id, client_secret, oauth_scope, redirect_uri):
```

The error in title is in this function:

```
FCU.crypting(client = None, access_token = None, client_id, client_secret, oauth_scope, redirect_uri)
```

Why? 
Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 7):

It's just what it says.  You can't pass non-keyword arguments after keyword arguments.  If you have something like `client=None`, that's a keyword argument, and all of those have to come at the *end* of the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with other method:

```
variable1 = None
variable2 = None

class.function(variable1, variable2, client_id, client_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out section 4.7.2 here:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html